# Replace specific characters with appropriate characters in given word

Tags: string, replace, go

I want to in words in sentence change every occurrence of `'n' with 'm'`, `'a' with 'e'` and  10 more rules. At the moment I am working calling sequental way for every rule like:

```
word = strings.Replace(word, "n", "m", -1)
word = strings.Replace(word, "a", "e", -1)
.... and 10 more times
```

Is there better way to replace in Go characters with another, given in map?

Answer (score 5):

Basically this is what the [`strings.Map()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map) function is for.

> Map returns a copy of the string s with all its characters modified according to the mapping function. If mapping returns a negative value, the character is dropped from the string with no replacement.

**Example** (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Pl7qHBHbMC)):

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Map(rules, "Try not to replace me"))
}

func rules(r rune) rune {
    switch r {
    case 'n':
        return 'm'
    case 'a':
        return 'e'
    default:
        return r
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Try mot to replece me
```

#### With a map

If you have many rules, you can shorten this code:

```
var repMap = map[rune]rune{
    'a': 'e', 'n': 'm',
}

func rules2(r rune) rune {
    if r2, ok := repMap[r]; ok {
        return r2
    }
    return r
}
```

Output is the same ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Pl7qHBHbMC)).

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to replace more than one letter, then [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer) is a very efficient way to go.

```
var r = strings.NewReplacer(
    "n", "m",
    "a", "e",
    "x", "ngma",
) // you can set it as a global variable and use it multiple times instead of creating a new one everytime. 

func main() {
    fmt.Println(r.Replace("ax is a nurderer"))
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/xXLmFptmtN)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a map with `string_from`, `string_to` and then applying it in a loop:

```
replacements := map[string]string{
    "n": "m",
    "a": "e",
}
for s_from, s_to := range(replacements){
    str = strings.Replace(str, s_from, s_to, -1)
}
```

this way all your rules are easily and compactly defined. And you will get something like <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/w9JTqg1A8k)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
r := strings.NewReplacer("n", "m", "a", "e")
fmt.Println(r.Replace("Try not to replace me"))
}
```

the result : http://play.golang.org/p/kW6J0GFSML
the document : http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReplacer